# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'imagePicker.openPicker')

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use react-native-image-crop-picker. The code is given below. I already tried doing npm install react-native-image-crop-picker@latest.

Whenever i select any one of the options undefined is not an object(evaluating 'imagePicker.openPicker')is shown. 
Please help fixing this issue.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Alert,
Image, TouchableOpacity, NativeModules, Dimensions
} from 'react-native';

var ImagePicker = NativeModules.ImageCropPicker;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    marginBottom: 10
  },
  text: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
});

export default class Upload extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      image: null,
      images: null
    };
  }

  pickSingleWithCamera(cropping) {
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
      cropping: cropping,
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
    }).then(image => {
      console.log('received image', image);
      this.setState({
        image: {uri: image.path, width: image.width, height: image.height},
        images: null
      });
    }).catch(e => alert(e));
  }

  pickSingleBase64(cropit) {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      cropping: cropit,
      includeBase64: true
    }).then(image => {
      console.log('received base64 image');
      this.setState({
        image: {uri: `data:${image.mime};base64,`+ image.data, width: image.width, height: image.height},
        images: null
      });
    }).catch(e => alert(e));
  }

  cleanupImages() {
    ImagePicker.clean().then(() => {
      console.log('removed tmp images from tmp directory');
    }).catch(e => {
      alert(e);
    });
  }

  cleanupSingleImage() {
    let image = this.state.image || (this.state.images && this.state.images.length ? this.state.images[0] : null);
    console.log('will cleanup image', image);

    ImagePicker.cleanSingle(image ? image.uri : null).then(() => {
      console.log(`removed tmp image ${image.uri} from tmp directory`);
    }).catch(e => {
      alert(e);
    })
  }

  cropLast() {
    if (!this.state.image) {
      return Alert.alert('No image', 'Before open cropping only, please select image');
    }

    openCropper({
      path: this.state.image.uri,
      width: 200,
      height: 200
    }).then(image => {
      console.log('received cropped image', image);
      this.setState({
        image: {uri: image.path, width: image.width, height: image.height, mime: image.mime},
        images: null
      });
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
      Alert.alert(e.message ? e.message : e);
    });
  }

  pickSingle(cropit, circular=false) {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      cropping: cropit,
      cropperCircleOverlay: circular,
      compressImageMaxWidth: 640,
      compressImageMaxHeight: 480,
      compressImageQuality: 0.5,
      compressVideoPreset: 'MediumQuality',
    }).then(image => {
      console.log('received image', image);
      this.setState({
        image: {uri: image.path, width: image.width, height: image.height, mime: image.mime},
        images: null
      });
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
      Alert.alert(e.message ? e.message : e);
    });
  }

  pickMultiple() {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      multiple: true,
      waitAnimationEnd: false
    }).then(images => {
      this.setState({
        image: null,
        images: images.map(i => {
          console.log('received image', i);
          return {uri: i.path, width: i.width, height: i.height, mime: i.mime};
        })
      });
    }).catch(e => alert(e));
  }

  scaledHeight(oldW, oldH, newW) {
    return (oldH / oldW) * newW;
  }

  renderVideo(video) {
    return (<View style={{height: 300, width: 300}}>
      <Video source={{uri: video.uri, type: video.mime}}
         style={{position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0
          }}
         rate={1}
         paused={false}
         volume={1}
         muted={false}
         resizeMode={'cover'}
         onError={e => console.log(e)}
         onLoad={load => console.log(load)}
         repeat={true} />
     </View>);
  }

  renderImage(image) {
    return <Image style={{width: 300, height: 300, resizeMode: 'contain'}} source={image} />
  }

  renderAsset(image) {
    if (image.mime && image.mime.toLowerCase().indexOf('video/') !== -1) {
      return this.renderVideo(image);
    }

    return this.renderImage(image);
  }

  render() {
    return (<View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
        {this.state.image ? this.renderAsset(this.state.image) : null}
        {this.state.images ? this.state.images.map(i => <View key={i.uri}>{this.renderAsset(i)}</View>) : null}
      </ScrollView>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.pickSingleWithCamera(false)} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Select Single With Camera</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.pickSingleWithCamera(true)} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Select Single With Camera With Cropping</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.pickSingle(false)} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Select Single</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.cropLast()} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Crop Last Selected Image</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.pickSingleBase64(false)} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Select Single Returning Base64</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.pickSingle(true)} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Select Single With Cropping</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.pickSingle(true, true)} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Select Single With Circular Cropping</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.pickMultiple.bind(this)} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Select Multiple</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.cleanupImages.bind(this)} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Cleanup All Images</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.cleanupSingleImage.bind(this)} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Cleanup Single Image</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    );
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also found in most of your functions, you are referring this.setState() but you didn't actually bind your functions to the component in your constructor.

Try to add these lines in your constructor:

```
this.pickSingleWithCamera = this.pickSingleWithCamera.bind(this)
```

And call this function from your component in this way if you want to pass a param:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.pickSingleWithCamera.bind(this, false)} style={styles.button}>
  <Text style={styles.text}>Select Single With Camera</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This is just for one of your function and you will need to do this for others. This might just work and I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Yes, Thanks the error did get fixed. But it is leading me to nowhere. I was expecting for it to launch gallery or something.

Comment: Avkrit Khati I am facing the same issue on iOS did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 5):

**Important!!!!!!!!!!!!!**
After many hours of debugging.
For Everyone who is using Expo. This doesn't work in EXPO while trying to build in windows.
Try form this instead.
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/

Answer (score 2):

I got rid of this by adding a folder `react-native-image-crop-picker` inside node_modules and run 
`cd ios`
`pod install`

Answer (score 0):

Have you import the module in your header? Try the following at the top of your code:

```
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';
```

Comment: yes i added. Now it is giving an error " undefined is not an object (evaluating 'reactNativeImageCropPicker2.default.openPicker) "

Comment: I haven't used this module before. But make sure you did all installation steps as described in the doc

    react-native link 

And update your react-native to the latest: npm install --save react-native@latest

Comment: Sir, could you please check my code in my other question that i have posted. Please help me. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943065/react-native-image-picker-doesnt-launch-gallery-when-i-select-the-option)

Comment: Did you able to sort this out? I see I'm having the same problem, though.